# Transparent look in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiz, transparency

Anyone here who knows where can I find a tutorial where I can make Ubuntu 9.04 - Ubuntu 10.04 look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, that style is still testing yet. for more, you can even check [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/12/lucid-to-get-aero-style-rgba.html).
that's pretty cool. I also can't wait for it anymore ;)

> Lucid Alpha testers may wish to test
>   and bug-hunt this shiny newly
>   empowered GTK+ out. You can find the
>   PPA you need for LUCID ONLY  @ 
>   https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-desktop/+archive/ppa.
>
> Bug reporting to be done @
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/491521

You've other choice of Theme. [LiNsta](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/LiNsta+%28LiNsta+is+Not+Vista+%3B-%29?content=42697)., [Aero Clone](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Aero-clone?content=57352). and [these awesome themes](http://www.sizzledcore.com/2008/08/09/ubuntu-themes-awesome-themes-for-linux/).

Answer (score 2):

Try application Ubuntu Tweak.